# What are the limitations of syncing PC settings (Firefox) with my Android?

Tags: firefox-for-android

Is it possible to sync the Firefox settings (including add-ons) on my PC with my Galaxy 10.1 tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant sync addons or settings between the PC and android due to differences in the platform. The only things which can be synced are bookmarks, passwords, history and even open tabs. Firefox 11's addon sync works only between the PC versions